# Possible mistake in Royden and Fitzpatrick's book Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Proposition 19(v) of Section 1.5 page 23 in the book *Real Analysis* by Royden and Fitzpatrick, 4th edition (see [link](http://math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/books/royden-fitzpatrick/royden-fitzpatrick.pdf)), says:

> If $a_n \le b_n$ for all $n$, then $\lim\sup a_n \le \lim \inf b_n$.

However one can find a counter-example for a sequence $a_n = b_n$ which has
different limsup and liminf. Is it a mistake, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Yes, this is an error. And your explanation of why it's wrong is exactly correct; I can't imagine why someone downvoted this.

Comment: I guess you have to swap $\liminf$ with $\limsup$.

Comment: I didn't vote up or down, but perhaps the downvote is because the poster links to an unabridged pdf of an unauthorized reprint of a copyrighted book. MSE tends to frown on such shenanigans.

Comment: @UmbertoP. That would be solved by an edit, not certainly a downvote.

Comment: Of course it would.

Comment: Are you sure that the link points to a legal copy of the book? If not, the link should be removed.

Comment: FYI: http://www.math.umd.edu/~pmf/err130405.pdf (This page is maintained by Fitzpatrick himself, so there is no legality concern here). This is in this list.

Comment: @UmbertoP. So Harvard/Curtis T McMullen is committing copyright infringement? It's not a link to some torrent site. It's a link to a Harvard webpage

Comment: @Ian Is that supposed to be the whole book? Or just errata? The webpage now says 'Not Found

The requested URL /~pmf/err130405.pdf was not found on this server.'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are right.

Take $a_n=0$ if $n$ is odd and $a_n=1$ if $n$ is even.

Take $b_n=a_n+0.5$

Then $\forall n$ $ a_n<b_n$ and $\limsup a_n=1$, $\liminf b_n=0.5$...

Answer (score 5):

You pinpointed the problem. Probably it's a typo and
$$
\liminf\{a_n\}\le\limsup\{b_n\}
$$
was meant.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, it’s a typo, indeed.

What *is* true is that if $a_n\leq b_n$ termwise, then *both* $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}b_n$$ *and* $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n$$ hold.